# How to retry a PostgreSQL serializable transaction with Spring?

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-retry

I am developing against a PostgreSQL v12 database. I am using [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) transactions. The general idea is that when PostgreSQL detects a serialization anomaly, one should retry the complete transaction.

I am using Spring's [`AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.html) to translate database exceptions to Spring's exception classes. This exception translator should translate the PostgreSQL error [`40001`/`serialization_failure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/errcodes-appendix.html) to a [`ConcurrencyFailureException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/ConcurrencyFailureException.html). Spring JDBC maintains a [mapping file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml#L261) to map the PostgreSQL-specific code `40001` to a generic `cannotSerializeTransactionCodes` class of database exceptions, which translates into a `ConcurrencyFailureException` for the API user.

My idea was to rely on the Spring Retry project to retry a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction which is halted due to a serialization error as following:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Retryable(include = ConcurrencyFailureException.class, maxAttempts = ..., backoff = ...)
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public @interface SerializableTransactionRetry {
}
```

In service implementation, I would simply replace `@Transactional` by `@SerializableTransactionRetry` and be done with it.

Now, back to PostgreSQL. Essentially, there are two stages at which a serialization anomaly can be detected:

1. during the execution of a statement
2. during the commit phase of a transaction

It seems that Spring's `AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator` is properly translating a serialization anomaly which is detected during the execution of a statement, but fails to translate one during the commit phase. Consider the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JDBC transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:332)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
```

As you can see, PostgreSQL detects a serialization anomaly (`ERROR: could not serialize access due to ...`), but this is translated by Spring into a [`TransactionSystemException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionSystemException.html) instead of a `ConcurrencyFailureException`.

I could alter the `SerializableTransactionRetry` annotation above to include a `TransactionSystemException` as well, but I believe that would be wrong, as now we will be retrying upon any kind of transaction error, which is not what we want here.

Is this a shortcoming in Spring's `AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator`? I am using Spring 5.2.1.

Comment: I also asked this on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24064. The general policy is to ask questions on SO and raise concrete issues on github, but I wasn't sure if this could be considered as an issue or not. I haven't found any definite resource which states what `ConcurrencyFailureException` **exactly** represents, so one could argue that a `AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator` is doing its job just fine. However, in that case, I would argue that it is not really practical to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24064#issuecomment-557800496, the [`SQLExceptionTranslator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html) is actually not used for SQL exceptions happening during the commit phase.

In the same ticket, a proposal has been made to introduce this in Spring 5.3 (which I believe will be released somewhere in Q2 2020).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spring-boot you can create a custom `DataSourceTransactionManager` and in its `doCommit` method throw one of `ConcurrencyFailureException` subclasses if the caught exception's sql error code is `40001`.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus;

@Component
public class MyDataSourceTransactionManager {

  @Bean
  DataSourceTransactionManager getDataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource) {
      @Override
      protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) {
        try {
          super.doCommit(status);
        } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
          Throwable throwable = e.getCause();
          if (throwable instanceof SQLException && "40001"
              .equals(((SQLException) throwable).getSQLState())) {
            throw new CannotSerializeTransactionException(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
          }
          throw e;
        }
      }
    };
  }

}
```

You can also use a `SQLExceptionTranslator` to translate the `SQLException` into a `DataAccessException` instead of checking the sql error code.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus;

@Component
public class MyDataSourceTransactionManager {

  @Bean
  DataSourceTransactionManager getDataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    final SQLExceptionTranslator exTranslator = new SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator(dataSource);
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource) {
      @Override
      protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) {
        try {
          super.doCommit(status);
        } catch (TransactionSystemException e) {
          if (e.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
            DataAccessException exception = exTranslator
                .translate("commit", null, (SQLException) e.getCause());
            if (!(exception instanceof UncategorizedSQLException)) {
              throw exception;
            }
          }
          throw e;
        }
      }
    };
  }

}
```